# Difference between const a = value; vs const a = () => (value);

Tags: javascript, performance, javascript-objects

I'd like to know if there's any difference (performance, memory usage) between the two following JS statements, whether it is recommended to use one over the other, and the reasoning behind it.

Statement 1 (assigning value)

```js
const fooOne = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const barOne = fooOne;
```

Statement 2 (using function expression)

```js
const fooTwo = () => ({ a: 1, b: 2 });
const barTwo = fooTwo();
```

Both statements yield the same thing:

```js
console.log(barOne); // outputs {a: 1, b: 2}
console.log(barTwo); // also outputs {a: 1, b: 2}
```

Comment: Most likely option 2 will take longer to run (as you now have a function to execute). Option 2 will take up more memory as you now have 2 objects, a function object and an object literal.

Comment: `fooTwo()` creates brand new object everytime but `barOne === fooOne`. Any changes to one object will affect the other variable because they are both pointing to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, using a arrow function is (mostly) a roundabout way of statement 1.

Changing one variable changes the other with statement type 1:

```js
const fooOne = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const barOne = fooOne;
barOne.a = 3;

// 3, 3
// Note: "const" object is modified
console.log(barOne.a, fooOne.a)


const fooTwo = () => ({ a: 1, b: 2 });
const barTwo = fooTwo();
barTwo.a = 3;

// 3, 1
console.log(barTwo.a, fooTwo().a)
```